# Как вставить тег в том месте, где мигает курсор без execCommand()?

Tags: курсор, javascript

На чистом javascript нужно вставить кросбраузерно тег в то место, где мигает курсор не используя команду `execCommand()`.

Это все дело в `iframe designMode="On"`.
Делаю редактор

и как узнать родительский тег курсора?

Comment: `место, где мигает курсор`    
это что за место такое

Comment: iframe designMode="On" ====>  а это вообще не понятно, что такое